# Jest, mocking return from await, I see results in console, but expect still fails

Tags: javascript, testing, async-await, jestjs, mocking

I have a pretty simple example of a mock working, updating the value correctly, but my test still fails.

`fetchStuff.js`:

```
const fetchStuff = async (entity, service) => {
    entity = await service.get();
    console.log('entity is an expected result!', entity); // this consoles out the expected value correctly.
}
```

`fetchStuff.spec.js`:

```
it('should...', () => {
    const expected = 'this will show up in console';
    const service.get = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => expected);
    let entity;

    fetchStuff(entity, service);

    expect(entity).toEqual(expected) // entity = 'undefined'
});
```

Every time, I see that `console.log` in the function is printing out the expected result, but some reason the `expect(entity)` is always `undefined`.

I've tried stuff like with `flush-promise`, I've tried removing the `await`. I've even seen the `done()`, technique, where we pass `done` in to `it`, ie `it('should...', done => {...})`

Not sure why I cannot get the correct expected, even tho the console is showing the expected result.

PS. I understand this is not respecting functional paradigm or pure functions. Please ignore that.

Comment: Fundamentally your function _doesn't_ do what you think it does, that's why the test fails. _JavaScript_ doesn't do what you think it does. Assigning a new value to the parameter name doesn't change anything outside the function, it's purely a local change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an asynchronous function, but testing right away, before the promise is resolved. You need an async/await in your test, if you are using asynchronous calls, like your await in the main function.

```
it('should...', async () => {
    const expected = 'this will show up in console';
    const service.get = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => expected);
    let entity;

    await fetchStuff(entity, service);

    expect(entity).toEqual(expected) // entity = 'undefined'
});
```

However, as per the comment on your question, the code may not be returning what you expect, so this change for async/await will not solve the problem on its own.

```
const fetchStuff = async (entity, service) => {
    entity = await service.get();
    console.log('entity is an expected result!', entity); 
    return entity;
}


it('should...', async () => {
    const expected = 'this will show up in console';
    const FakeService = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(expected),

    const entity = await FakeService();
    expect(entity).toBe(expected) ;
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this technique too, but it did not work. Honestly expected this one to work above all, because I remember doing it in React, in one form or another. My example is an abstraction from a `mounted` method in a `vue` component. So maybe I need to move over to asking the question in the vue forum, since they must have a way of testing the `propData` change, after the component went through the `mounted` lifecycle.

Comment: The comment from jonrsharpe in your question is about the code, and it is likely not working as you expect.  If the code itself, your regular function is not working properly, the test will not work either, as the code under test is flawed.  Maybe the function you are referring to in Vue, does something special with setting values, so they return.

Comment: Yes, the solution did live in the vue world, something like `wrapper.vm.entity` works, as long as I do as the answer suggests and use `async/await` in my test suite. I am going to accept the `async/await` answer, since it is the most applicable to the problem I was having. I suspect the `async/await` and `wrapper.vm` combination threw me off, so I abstracted it into more primitive jscript, but forgetting the natural lexical scope functionality.